# Как ограничить поиск города в яндекс картах по определенной стране (странам), конкретному региону?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть функция, которая принимает на вход название город (`city`)

и выводит список всех объектов которые нашлись в яндекс.картах с таким названием названием

```
console.log(point);
```

можно ли как то ограничить поиск по отдельной стране, списку стран, региону?

```
function geolist(city) {
  var Geocoder = ymaps.geocode(city);
  Geocoder.then(
    function(res) {
      if (res.geoObjects.getLength()) {
        res.geoObjects.events;
        $(res.geoObjects.events.types.mapchange).each(function(i) {
          var point = res.geoObjects.get(i);
          if (typeof(point) != 'undefined') {
            console.log(point);
          }
        });
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      alert("Возникла ошибка: " + error.message);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В API 2.1 пока нет возможности ограничить область поиска или геокодирования страной, регионом или городом через параметр запроса.

Есть три варианта как добиться похожего поведения доступными средствами:

- Задавать прямоугольную область поиска при геокодированиии [опцией `boundedBy](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/?from=SO#param-options.boundedBy).
- Дописывать в запрос к геокодеру название страны или региона в дополнение к `city`.
- Фильтровать по стране/региону ответ геокодера самостоятельно до вывода на карту.